# Facebook login in parse after migration

Tags: node.js, xcode, facebook, parse-platform, windows-server-2012-r2

I completed all the steps of migrating from parse to my local server windows server 2012R2 deployed **mongoDB** and the **parse server** and the **node.js** and **python** on the server and of course installed the webserver role on the window.

I am now successfully listening to port 1337 for connections and I connected my node.js to the mongoDB and also accepted connections successfully to the database via port 27017. Entered my new app keys and client keys and updated them on my application. But my application has facebook login. And for sure when I open the app to login it gives me an error in the console saying "**facebook auth is not configured**". Ordinary user login is working but the Facebook one is not.
I think there was a way that I can add my facebook app ID to the nodejs index file where I updated all the keys. But I really don't know how to do it. If any body has experience in deploying parse on his own web server please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: did you setup a work around? Just using FB SDK to log in and create the User manually?